# z-index not indexing properly

Tags: html, css

Alright, so this code generates two blocks in a div. The top block should go over the bottom block because the top has a higher z-index, but when I give the bottom block a margin-top: -30px it goes above the top block.

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div style="width: 300px; height: 90px; overflow: hidden;">
        <div style="width:300px; height: 50px; z-index: 2; background-color: #ff0000;">
        </div>

        <div style="width:300px; height: 50px; z-index: 1; background-color: #ff00ff; margin-top: -30px;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I get the top block to go above the bottom block?

Comment: (hope it's just for demo purposes but) You should avoid using inline styles... It's terribly hard to work-with and maintain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `z-index` property [only applies to positioned elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#layers).

You could add `position: relative` and it will work as expected [(example)](http://jsfiddle.net/q0L6yL7h/).

The default value of the `position` property is `static`, which is why it wasn't working.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I'll accept ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

Add `position:relative;` in css of both blocks:

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 90px; overflow: hide;">
        <div style="position: relative; width:300px; height: 50px; z-index: 2; background-color: #ff0000;">
        </div>
        <div style="position: relative; width:300px; height: 50px; z-index: 1; background-color: #ff00ff; margin-top: -30px;">
        </div>
    </div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uu721kgc/